# Is it useful turn on "keep alive" for Tor SOCKS5 TCP connection?

Tags: torsocks, socks

Wasabi Wallet application connects to the [Tor SOCKS5](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/socks-extensions.txt) endpoint ([code](https://github.com/zkSNACKs/WalletWasabi/blob/13fdc1566b626ac2dc56c33f0eb707bcab04e55b/WalletWasabi/Tor/Socks5/TorTcpConnectionFactory.cs#L77-L93)) and it specifies various "keep alive" options for that socket connections. Note that the TCP connections connect the application and Tor both of which runs on the same machine and under the same user.

Is it necessary to specify that keep-alive options? Is it recommended? Is it useless?

Answer (score 1):

Asked the question here as well:
https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/tor/-/issues/40653